# Create HTTPS client in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, https, node.js

I've been having a heck of a time figuring out how to use Node.js (v0.3.8) to securely connect to an HTTP server. I have the following code:

```
var http = require("http");
var client = http.createClient(443, host, /* secure= */ true);
var request = client.request("GET", relativeUrl, { host: host });
```

When I run it, I get:

```
node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Parse Error
    at Client.onData [as ondata] (http.js:1287:27)
    at Client._onReadable (net.js:648:27)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:156:10)
```

I've been Googling for answers for the past half hour, and have read the documentation at http://nodejs.org/ .  What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out I was using an old version of the Node documentation, which didn't include a reference to the `https` module. Referring to the current docs, I found http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback, which provides an example:

```
https.get({ host: 'encrypted.google.com', path: '/' }, function (res) { … });
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using node.js as a client you should be able to simply substitute http for https.

That is according to the following website
https://github.com/danwrong/Restler/

```
"Transparently handle SSL (just specify https in the URL)"
```

Comment: I'll look into using Restler, I hadn't encountered it previously. On examining the source, I did notice that it uses the `https` module, which helped me find the answer to my question. Thank you!