# How do I configure nodejs/expressjs to serve pages over https?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a certificate and key, and I'm looking to serve my pages over https. How do I configure nodejs/expressjs to do so?

I'm explicitly looking to do this through the expressjs library.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/https.html ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create HTTPS client in NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940646/create-https-client-in-nodejs)

Comment: @Shoban the linked question uses nodejs as a client, not a server.

Comment: @Shoban I'm looking for the equivalent to that, in expressjs. Maybe expressjs doesn't implement a https server yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use 0.2.4. you can use

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require("fs");
var crypto = require('crypto');

var app = express.createServer();
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem').toString();
var credentials = crypto.createCredentials({key: privateKey, cert: certificate});
app.setSecure(credentials);
```

but this not possible if you use node 0.4, as you can't call setSecure() to convert a server as SSL. One must create an instance of https.Server.

i don't know if there are any future plan to support this

Comment: express now supporting creating an HTTPS server

    var app = require('express').createServer({ key: ... });