# Listen on HTTP and HTTPS for a single express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, express

Can I create an Express server listening on both HTTP and HTTPS, with the same routes and the same middlewares?

Currently I do this with Express on HTTP, with [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) tunneling HTTPS to Express, but I prefer a pure Node solution.

I can do it with this code, but using the `handle` method that is marked as private:

```
var express = require( 'express' )
    , https = require("https")
    , fs = require( 'fs' );

var app = express.createServer();
// init routes and middlewares
app.listen( 80 );

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync( 'privatekey.pem' ).toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync( 'certificate.pem' ).toString();
var options = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
https.createServer( options, function(req,res)
{
    app.handle( req, res );
} ).listen( 443 );
```

Comment: Answered succinctly here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23894573/1882064

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can share the implementation via something like:

```
var register = function (app) {
    // config middleware
    app.configure({

    });

    // config routes
    app.get(...);
};

var http = express.createServer();
register(http);
http.listen(80);

var https = express.createServer({ key: /* https properties */ });
register(https);
https.listen(443);
```

Comment: This solution is now deprecated. Is there a newer solution?

Comment: @CMN - See cmd's solution below.  It works with current versions of Node (v4.4.2) and Express (4.13.4)

Answer (score 64):

To enable your app to listen for both `http` and `https` on ports `80` and `443` respectively, do the following

Create an express app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

The app returned by `express()` is a JavaScript function. It can be be passed to Node’s HTTP servers as a callback to handle requests. This makes it easy to provide both HTTP and HTTPS versions of your app using the same code base.

You can do so as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ca.pem')
};

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

For complete detail see the [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Answer (score 38):

As a possible update to this question, you might want to check out the changes [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) for express 3.  The change document says:

> The return value of `express()` is a JavaScript Function,
>   encapsulating everything that makes an Express app tick. This means
>   you can easily setup HTTP and HTTPS versions of your application by
>   passing it to node's `http.createServer()` and `https.createServer()`:

In Express 3, `express.createServer()` is now `express()`

Here is a complete example for express 3:

```
var fs = require('fs')
    , https = require('https')
    , http = require('http')
    , express = require('express')
    , keys_dir = 'keys/'
    , server_options = {
        key  : fs.readFileSync(keys_dir + 'privatekey.pem'),
        ca   : fs.readFileSync(keys_dir + 'certauthority.pem'),
        cert : fs.readFileSync(keys_dir + 'certificate.pem')
      }
    , app = express();
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.session( { secret: '' } ));
  app.use(app.router);
});
app.configure('development',function(){
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions: true, showStack:true}));
  app.set('view options', { pretty: true });
});
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
https.createServer(server_options,app).listen(7000);
http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
```

Comment: It's preferable to answer a question using the same language that the asker used. I have taken the liberty of translating the coffeescript to vanilla JS.

Answer (score 3):

You can use express and https in same port.

this works for me.

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const cors=require('cors');
const path=require("path");
const routes=require('./routes/api');
const routerComplain=require('./routes/api');
const routerstores=require('./routes/api');
const routerstock=require('./routes/api');
const routerreport=require('./routes/api');
const routeritem=require('./routes/api');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const routerRegister=require('./routes/api');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
require("dotenv").config();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@',{ useNewUrlParser: true },(err)=>{
    if(!err){
        console.log('db connected')
    }else{
        console.log('error in db')
    }
});

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin:'http://localhost:3000'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")))

app.use('/reg',routes);
app.use('/complain',routerComplain);
app.use('/register',routerRegister);
app.use('/stores',routerstores);
app.use('/reports',routerreport);
app.use('/stock',routerstock);
app.use('/items',routeritem);

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  })

const port = process.env.port||4000;

server.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('now listening for request');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the traditional two ports, one of the above solutions probably works, but using httpolyglot, you can really easily have http and https on the same port with the same middlewares.

https://github.com/mscdex/httpolyglot

Here's some skeleton code that worked for me:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var httpolyglot = require('httpolyglot');
var app = express();

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/certs/key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/certs/cer.cer")
};

httpolyglot.createServer(options, app).listen(port);
```

and if you want http -> https forwarding, you can just add this middleware function before the createServer() call:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.secure ) {
            res.redirect (301, 'https://' + req.hostname + ':port' + req.originalUrl);
    }
    next();
});
```

This  can be set up on a custom port

Comment: Neat...is there a benefit to putting them on the same port?

Answer (score 0):

Similar post

[Can I configure expressjs to serve some pages over http and others over https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159521/can-i-configure-expressjs-to-serve-some-pages-over-http-and-others-over-https)

Be aware that express now support creating Https servers with:

```
 var app = require('express').createServer({ key: ... });
```

Comment: I know how to create a HTTPS server, but not a server responding both on HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Did you read the other post? There is an example in the post. You create 2 server instances and make one listen on port 80 and one on 443, Http and Https.

Comment: Yes, I read the other post: there are 2 server instances with different routes. I want the same routes for both (or only one instance listening on HTTP and HTTPS).

Comment: you could declare the route functions separately and then use them to declare the route for both servers. Other than that option I don't know of a simple way to do what you are trying to do. Why would you need to serve the same content over both http and https?

Comment: Because this server content will be included in HTTP and HTTPS sites. I can declare the routes and middlewares for both servers, but I hoped I could do better.

Comment: Not that I can think of off the top of my head. Sorry

Comment: I started with listening to both http and https but then I scraped the idea and used nginx to do request handling (both http and https) and use http only in my node app. Much easier life in production, dev and testing.