# Adding https into bin/www

Tags: node.js, express

How do I add https(`require('https').createServer(options, onConnection).listen(443);`) into bin/www:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('test');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am trying to add https on expressjs bin/www, app.listen is using express().listen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen on HTTP and HTTPS for a single express app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355473/listen-on-http-and-https-for-a-single-express-app)

Comment: You don't need to listen on https if you then use a web server as proxy to host the app.