# Error: listen EADDRINUSE 3443

Tags: node.js

I have two `app.listens` in the code and I get an error ,when I take one of them out ,the authentication stops working ,how can I resolve the problem ,I'm trying to implement passport js into my app (I have followed a tutorial and I have passport js example working I just want to implement it to myproject )this is the following error I'm getting

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgcUR.jpg)

```
   'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const https =require('https')
const path = require('path')

var app         = express();

var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var morgan      = require('morgan');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');

var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('./config'); // get our config file
var Index   = require('./api/planner/index'); // get our mongoose model


var port = process.env.PORT || 3443; // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
mongoose.connect(config.database); // connect to database
app.set('superSecret', config.secret); // secret variable

// use body parser so we can get info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// use morgan to log requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// =======================
// routes ================
// =======================
// basic route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});

// API ROUTES -------------------
// get an instance of the router for api routes
var apiRoutes = express.Router(); 

// TODO: route to authenticate a user (POST http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate)
apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
 // find the user
  User.findOne({
    name: req.body.name
  }, function(err, user) {

    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
    } else if (user) {

      // check if password matches
      if (user.password != req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
      } else {

        // if user is found and password is right
        // create a token
        var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
          expiresIn: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
        });

        // return the information including token as JSON
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Enjoy your token!',
          token: token
        });
      }   

    }

  });
});
// TODO: route middleware to verify a token
apiRoutes.use(function(req, res, next) {

  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  // decode token
  if (token) {

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {      
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
      } else {
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        req.decoded = decoded;    
        next();
      }
    });

  } else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({ 
        success: false, 
        message: 'No token provided.' 
    });

  }
});

// route to show a random message (GET http://localhost:8080/api/)
apiRoutes.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'Welcome to the coolest API on earth!' });
});

// route to return all users (GET http://localhost:8080/api/users)
apiRoutes.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.json(users);
  });
});   

// apply the routes to our application with the prefix /api
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
// we'll get to these in a second
app.get('/setup', function(req, res) {

  // create a sample user
  var nick = new User({ 
    name: 'Nick Cerminara', 
    password: 'password',
    admin: true 
  });

  // save the sample user
  nick.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('User saved successfully');
    res.json({ success: true });
  });
});



// =======================
// start the server ======
// =======================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:' + port);


const directoryToServe = 'client'
//const port = 3443

app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'..',directoryToServe)))

const httpsOptions = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','server.crt')),
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','server.key'))
}

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
.listen(port, function()
{
  console.log(`Serving the ${directoryToServe}/directory at https://localhost:${port}`)})

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');






app.use(bodyParser.json());
app
app.get('/',  function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("We're up and running!!!");
});


var plan = require('./api/planner/index');

app.get('/api/planner',plan.index);
app.post('/api/planner',plan.create);
app.put('/api/planner/:id',plan.update);
app.delete('/api/planner/:id',plan.delete);




console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
//
```

Comment: Do you use windows? How many command windows do you have open?

Comment: Yes,one ,it's nothing to do with other windows ,when I take out `app.listen(port);` ,I get no errors but then the localhost does not work

Comment: This port is used by another. Take another port number

Comment: I tried still does not work

Comment: Something's already using that port. You may be calling `listen` twice for some reason.

Comment: Are you using different ports for the `https` and the `http` server? maybe try with different ones. and I think they should both be on the bottom. and you are using `bodyParser` twice for some reason. Usually I see it used once only http://stackoverflow.com/a/34644286/1893672

Answer (score 1):

This err is probably caused by using a busy port. If you are using ubuntu, you can check the status of ports by `lsof -i:portnumber`. After running the command you will have a PID.
You can release the port by `kill -9 pid`.

Windows and mac have similar commands.

Comment: Windows doesn't have `lsof`, though.

Comment: for windows cases you can take a look at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. @TheGiantBeast