# access static files using local ip address

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

when i run my server using localhost it works normally
but when i run it using local ip address which is 192.168.1.6 css and js file are not loaded giving this error :

GET https://192.168.1.6/js/auth.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET https://192.168.1.6/css/auth.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

this is the link line in the ejs file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/auth.css" />
<script src="/js/auth.js"></script>
```

i tryied to access these files using browser with link : https://192.168.1.6/js/auth.js and it returns :Not Found

but when i change https to http it works.
what should i do to load css and js files without switching my server to https

Comment: The HTTPS protocol ensures a secure and encrypted connection between the client (browser) and server. Getting this to work requires a lot more setup. You will need to generate certificates and install them as well as configure your server to use these certificates and listen for network activity on port 443. You generally don't need to do this when testing locally unless you are trying to validate that your app works over HTTPS. Try googling "enable SSL for local development".

Comment: And to explain why you are getting "Not found" - this is because when you use HTTPS, you are implicitly making requests to PORT 443. For example, these two URLs are the same: `https://google.com`, `https://google.com:443`. Since there is no server listening on PORT 443, you will get "Not found". When you use HTTP, you are implicitly making requests over PORT 80. This works because your server code includes something like `server.listen(80)`.

Comment: @RyanWheale If there's no server listening on port 443 you'll get a connection error, not "404 not found".

Comment: @Barmar You are correct - my mistake. I suppose there are a couple things that could trigger Not Found - most of them boil down to a misconfigured server. Basically the server is getting the request but doesn't know what to do with it. Here's an example of how to listen on both :80 and :443 using express - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355473/listen-on-http-and-https-for-a-single-express-app

Comment: It's possible something else (like Skype, sometimes!) is listening on port 443.

Comment: I am using xampp for mysql server and the apache server is running on 8080 and 443 ports